# Empty result in association parent-children when there are not children

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following schema:

**hours table**: this table has "constant" data, it never changes because only will store the schedule-able hours

```
hour (int)
----
8
9
10
```

**appointments table**

```
hour (int)  |  date (text)
--------------------------
10          | 25/08/2015
```

In my application I want to show only available hours to set a new appointment based in hour-date filter. For example, I can say that for the days:

- `25/08/2015`: available hours are `8` and `9` because `10` is already taken
- `26/08/2015`: available hours are `8`, `9` and `10` because there are not appointments at that date.

At the beginning I was using this query:

```
select h.hour 
from hours h, appointment a 
where h.hour != a.hour and a.date = 'the-date';
```

This query only works if there are appointments in the given dates, but for the rest of dates without appointments it returns empty result. I can achieve this task via application, but I am trying to exhaust all db's possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join), but a subquery might be easier to understand:

```
SELECT hour
FROM hours
WHERE hour NOT IN (SELECT hour
                   FROM appointment
                   WHERE date = ?)
```